# Как можно динамически подгружать и удалять стили в React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router, style

Всем привет. Переношу проект на со статики на React. В проекте много страниц, пока около 10, но в теории будет больше 100 и для каждой написан свой стиль. Приложение сделано в духе минимума передаваемых данных. Для перехода решил использовать Route. И столкнулся с такой проблемой, стили между страницами накладываются друг на друга. Это плохо как со стороны дизайн так как верстка едет да и если представить что пользователь пройдется по нескольким страницам, пускай посидит часик, пройдется по страницам 100 человек и это уже почти гиг ненужных данных на странице в виде не используемых стилей.

Я решил перебрать пару вариантов:
Пытался производить импорт внутри render или писать ...</> с нужными стилями а старые подчищать. Но ничего не работает.
Можно ли как-то подчищать стили в пределах Route, чтобы при удалении компонента импортированные стили удалялись?

Comment: Интересно на сколько целесообразно удалять подгруженные стили. Первый раз слышу, что это проблема. А то что они пересекаются, то это можно исправить CSS modules

Comment: Представьте ситуацию. Человек сидит в телефоне. Прошелся по 100, 200 страницам и тд, не закрыл приложение. А завтра еще посидел и посмотрел еще пару сотен страниц. И все продолжается на протяжении месяца. Вполне обычное поведение среднестатистического пользователя. Что будет с его памятью?

Comment: Ничего не будет, если  браузер удаляет из памяти просмотренные страницы. Если вы их накапливаете в памяти сами, то это явно не проблема реакта или стилей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моим решением оказалось просто, при открытии нового роута (где импортируется новый стиль) удалять старый тег style

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).